# Ember.js performance bottleneck in RenderBuffer.string()

Tags: ember.js

I am debugging a performance problem for an app. Drilled down to what appears to be a clue: `Ember.RenderBuffer.string()` took over 4 seconds for one of the elements. When drilling down more into the code, it was the function `setInnerHTMLWithoutFix` that was the culprit: it searches the template HTML for script tags injected by Metamorph, and then replaces them all one by one, but to do this it has to traverse the dom for each of the matches: and there were over 400 matches! We must have a large view, but I'd love to see if anyone encountered this before and/or any pointers to fixing or working around this problem.

Comment: What browser are you seeing this in? The function you mentioned has very different codepaths depending on browser feature detection. If you could create a JSFiddle for this, I would be willing to profile it and see if I can help.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use the super B feature on ember inspector [get it here for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en)

that now has render performance and you can see and evaluate any bottleneck in Render

[image]